# Solving the cubic $2t^{3} - 3t_{1}t^{2} + t_{1}^{3} = 0$

Tags: parametric, cubics

The question is:

"**4.** Find the equation of the tangent and the equation of the normal to the curve $x = 3t^{2}$, $y = t^{3}$ at the point whose parameter is $t_{1}$. Find the parameter of the point at which the tangent meets the curve again."

By differentiating $x$ and $y$ with respect to $t$ and using the chain rule, we find:

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{t}{2}$

Using $y - y_{1} = m(x - x_{1})$ we find the equation of the tangent at the point where $t = t_{1}$ to be:

$2y - t_{1}x + t_{1}^{3} = 0$.

For those who are interested, the equation of the normal is:

$t_{1}y + 2x - (t_{1}^{4} + 6t_{1}^{2}) = 0$.

By using the equation of the tangent, and the fact that the line meets the curve at the points $(3t^{2}, t^{3})$, we find:

$2t^{3} - 3t_{1}t^{2} + t_{1}^{3} = 0$

But I am stuck on how to solve this cubic - can anybody help?

Comment: Since $t = t_{1}$ is a root, you can divide by $t - t_{1}$, then factor or (at worst) use the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
2t^3-3t_1t^2+t_1^3= (t-t_1)(2t^2-t_1t -t_1^2)
$$

Comment: Thanks, I'm not used to such abstract polynomial long division

Comment: here use: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini's_rule, not long division.